# How can I save part of URL using Katalon?

Tags: url, katalon-studio, katalon

I would like to save part of the URL and I don't really know how to do it. I would like to save the part of the URL in a variable.

Anyone has an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to get the current url, use

```
current_url = WebUI.getUrl()
```

Then you will need to use some kind of string manipulations to get the part that you need.

Katalon uses Groovy language, so you can read about the string methods [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_strings.htm).

For example, if `current_url='https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_strings.htm'` you wish to get only the part of the url after the last `/` try something like this:

```
split_url = current_url.split('/')
partial_url = split_url[split_url.size()-1]
println partial_url
```

The result of the above is "groovy_strings.htm".